# Write to plist when UIButton selected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, plist, property-list

I'm making this code to set a default state for a UIButton in my DetailViewController, dependig on a strings value in a plist array with dictionaries. This works fine (in viewDidLoad).

Then I want to write to the plist when favoriteButtonPressed, but this isn't working. I think something in the code is wrong. Can you help me with a correction?

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

//The selectedObject property is recieved through segue from TableViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedObject;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL favoriteButtonSelected;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *favoriteButton;

-(IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize selectedObject;

@synthesize favoriteButtonSelected;

@synthesize favoriteButton;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

if ([[selectedObject valueForKey:@"Favorite"] isEqual:@"Yes"])  {

    [favoriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritedItem.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [favoriteButton setSelected:YES];
    [favoriteButton setHighlighted:YES];
    favoriteButtonSelected = 1;

} else {

    [favoriteButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [favoriteButton setSelected:NO];
    [favoriteButton setHighlighted:NO];
    favoriteButtonSelected = 0;
}
}

//Action to write to plist

-(IBAction)favoriteButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:@"Objects" ofType:@"plist"];

if (favoriteButtonSelected == 0) {

    [sender setSelected:YES];
    [sender setHighlighted:YES];

    favoriteButtonSelected = 1;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favoritedItem.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [selectedObject setValue:@"Yes" forKey:@"Favorite"];
    [selectedObject writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

} else {

    [sender setSelected:NO];
    [sender setHighlighted:NO];

    favoriteButtonSelected = 0;
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notFavorite.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [selectedObject setValue:@"No" forKey:@"Favorite"];
    [selectedObject writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which problem you encounter.
I assume it's related to you trying to write to your application bundle directory.
This is discouraged in the [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html). You should read its "File System Basics" and "Accessing Files and Directories" chapters.

The general gist is that you should copy your "Objects.plist" to the "Library" folder on first start and then read from and write to there.

Comment: Can you show me how to copy the plist to the library and make the new path to it?